# How can i delete a section of Json when a pattern occurs

Tags: json, api, sed, jq

I am using an API to retrieve some football data, i have noticed that when a certain pattern occurs, the data is corrupt.

Here is an example of the correct data format:

```
 {
    "id": 150,
    "name": "bwin",
    "odds": {
      "data": [
        {
          "value": "15.50",
          "handicap": null,
          "total": null,
          "label": "1",
          "probability": "6.45%",
          "dp3": "15.500",
          "american": 1450,
          "factional": null,
          "winning": false,
          "stop": false,
          "bookmaker_event_id": null,
          "last_update": {
            "date": "2019-11-29 16:02:57.421588",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "UTC"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": "7.50",
          "handicap": null,
          "total": null,
          "label": "X",
          "probability": "13.33%",
          "dp3": "7.500",
          "american": 650,
          "factional": null,
          "winning": false,
          "stop": false,
          "bookmaker_event_id": null,
          "last_update": {
            "date": "2019-11-29 16:02:57.421630",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "UTC"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": "1.10",
          "handicap": null,
          "total": null,
          "label": "2",
          "probability": "90.91%",
          "dp3": "1.100",
          "american": -1000,
          "factional": null,
          "winning": true,
          "stop": false,
          "bookmaker_event_id": null,
          "last_update": {
            "date": "2019-11-29 16:02:57.421656",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "UTC"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

As you can see each block starts with this order:
value, handicap, total, label.

However, sometimes the data is corrupt, i have found a pattern in the responses that i can use to know the data is corrupt, each little section always begins with label and value:

```
 {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "188Bet",
        "odds": {
          "data": [
            {
              "label": "1",
              "value": "1.04",
              "probability": "96.15%",
              "dp3": "1.040",
              "american": -2500,
              "factional": null,
              "winning": false,
              "handicap": null,
              "total": null,
              "bookmaker_event_id": null,
              "last_update": {
                "date": "2019-11-29 16:35:31.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "UTC"
              }
            },
            {
              "label": "X",
              "value": "9.50",
              "probability": "10.53%",
              "dp3": "9.500",
              "american": 850,
              "factional": null,
              "winning": false,
              "handicap": null,
              "total": null,
              "bookmaker_event_id": null,
              "last_update": {
                "date": "2019-11-29 16:35:31.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "UTC"
              }
            },
            {
              "label": "2",
              "value": "18.00",
              "probability": "5.56%",
              "dp3": "18.000",
              "american": 1700,
              "factional": null,
              "winning": true,
              "handicap": null,
              "total": null,
              "bookmaker_event_id": null,
              "last_update": {
                "date": "2019-11-29 16:35:31.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "UTC"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
```

the problem is my API response contains 100's of the above segments at once, is it possible to use JQ / sed or any other shell tool to remove the segments of json that contain the corrupt pattern? if so how can i achieve this?

I have been trying to to remove the corrupt data however the only way i can achieve it is by splitting the data in to one segment per file and then deleting the files that contain the corrupt pattern, but i am wondering if there is a quicker way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you observed might be spurious, but here's a jq filter that solves the problem in accordance with my understanding of the criterion you defined:

```
.odds.data |= map(if keys_unsorted[0:2] - ["label","value"] == [] 
                  then empty else . end)
```

Or, if the ordering of the keys is relevant:

```
.odds.data |= map(select(keys_unsorted[0:2] != ["label","value"]))
```

Comment: is this jq? i have tried running: cat file | jq .odds.data |= map(select(keys_unsorted[0:2] != ["label","value"])) , but getting error how do i use this command?

Comment: Yes.  It looks like you didn't put the jq program within single quotation marks. If you don't know how to quote the jq filter properly, the simplest would probably be to put the jq program into a file, and then invoke jq with the -f option.